# Is the other person notified if I follow then unfollow a person on github?

Tags: github

I accidentally followed someone on Github. Then I unfollowed them within 2 minutes, will the person receive any notification?

Answer (score 1):

You won't get notified, but it does show up in your "following" feed like this:
[image: following feed]

[image: example of someone following me]

Answer (score 0):

No. I have set my [notification settings](https://github.com/settings/notifications) such that I receive all types of notifications. Despite this, I have never received a notification about someone following me (despite seeing followers in my followers list). The only way to tell if someone is following you is to check the list on your profile page.